# How can I filter items into two separate lists from one array using pug?

Tags: sorting, pug, logical-operators, templating

I am attempting to create a pug mixin that can handle different formatting depending on the length of the generated list. I have it able to accept unlimited values, and can generate a single list no problem.

When I try to sort the items by index in order to create multiple lists, the code either generates a new `<ul>` for each `<li>` or nothing at all for the longer list formatting.

How can I make it so if the length of the items array is greater than 5, it puts the first 5 items in list 1 and the rest in the second list?

Code:

```html
mixin panelList(...items)
  if items.length < 6
      ul.list-unstyled.col.col-12.col-lg-12.d-none.d-lg-inline
        each item in items
          li.list-item.my-lg-1= item
  else   
      each item in items    
         .row.row-12
           while index < 6 
             ul.list-unstyled.col.col-12.col-lg-6.offset-sm-4.offset-md-0.offset-lg-0.d-none.d-lg-inline
               li.list-item.my-lg-1= item
          while index > 5 
             ul.list-unstyled.col.col-12.col-lg-12.d-none.d-lg-inline
               li.list-item.my-lg-1= item
```

```
mixin panelList(...items)
  if items.length < 6
      ul.list-unstyled.col.col-12.col-lg-12.d-none.d-lg-inline
        each item in items
          li.list-item.my-lg-1= item
  else   
      each item in items
       .row.row-12
          while index < 6 
             ul.list-unstyled.col.col-12.col-lg-6.offset-sm-4.offset-md-0.offset-lg-0.d-none.d-lg-inline
               li.list-item.my-lg-1= item
          while index > 5 
             ul.list-unstyled.col.col-12.col-lg-12.d-none.d-lg-inline
               li.list-item.my-lg-1= item
```

implemented via:

`+panelList("this", "is", "working", "great")` works fine

problem is with a list like:

`+panelList("this", "is", "not", "working", "quite", "as", "intended", "yet")`

I have tried sorting by `%` but it generates a new `<ul>` for each item. I have tried using item.index and index. I have tried using `for` and `if` instead of `while` before index < 6 also.

Comment: If anyone needs more clarification in order to assist with this please let me know